# Ajax json display data correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to display the data from json in my HTML. It doesn't seem to get the data properly. 
I'm running it on my localhost so I can see the json properly. here on my demo, the json is hosted on my personal FTP.

- How can I display the data in my HTML?

```js
$(function() {
  ajaxJS();
  function ajaxJS(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.domenghini.com/sample-data.json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html_to_append = '';
        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          html_to_append +=
            '<div class="col-3 mb-3"><div class="name text-left pb-1 text-uppercase"><p>' +
            name.first +
            '<div class="col-3 mb-3"><div class="last text-right pb-1 text-uppercase"><p>' +
            name.last +
            '</p></div><img  class="image img-fluid" src="' +
            picture +
            '" /><p class="company">' +
            company +
            '</p></div>';
        });
        $("#items-container").html(html_to_append);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="items-container" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your response data?  show us. data.items is important here to answer your question

Comment: `error: function(err) {
        console.error(err.statusText);
      }` fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you are trying to access `name.first` `name.last` in $.each without specifying `items.name.first`

```js
$(function() {
  ajaxJS();
  function ajaxJS(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.domenghini.com/sample-data.json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html_to_append = '';
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          html_to_append +=
            '<div class="col-3 mb-3"><div class="name text-left pb-1 text-uppercase"><p>' +
            item.name.first +
            '<div class="col-3 mb-3"><div class="last text-right pb-1 text-uppercase"><p>' +
            item.name.last +
            '</p></div><img  class="image img-fluid" src="' +
            item.picture +
            '" /><p class="company">' +
            item.company +
            '</p></div>';
        });
        $("#items-container").html(html_to_append);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="items-container" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the parameter for the `$.each()` function must be just `data` not `data.items`.

Comment: @user3699998 we asked you to show us what is data? without showing us how can we answer your question? by imagination only i answered now. would yourplease show us what data has?

Comment: @Dinesh you can see datas from his API : http://www.domenghini.com/sample-data.json. @user3699998, as @Guillaume said, replace `data.items`by `data`, then made the changes with @Dinesh post.

Comment: there's a CORS error with my server, but locally works fine, just the datas aren't showing

Comment: @user3699998 accept the answer please and upvote.  thanks